# Apache Spark SQL issue : java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.517] failure: identifier expected

Tags: join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As per the my investigation on spark sql, come to know that more than 2 tables can't be joined directly, we have to use sub query to make it work. So I am using sub query and able to join 3 tables :

with following query :

> "SELECT name, age, gender, dpi.msisdn, subscriptionType,
>   maritalStatus, isHighARPU, ipAddress, startTime, endTime, isRoaming,
>   dpi.totalCount, dpi.website FROM (SELECT subsc.name, subsc.age,
>   subsc.gender, subsc.msisdn, subsc.subscriptionType,
>   subsc.maritalStatus, subsc.isHighARPU, cdr.ipAddress, cdr.startTime,
>   cdr.endTime, cdr.isRoaming FROM SUBSCRIBER_META subsc, CDR_FACT cdr
>   WHERE subsc.msisdn = cdr.msisdn AND cdr.isRoaming = 'Y') temp,
>   DPI_FACT dpi WHERE temp.msisdn = dpi.msisdn";

But when in the same pattern, i am trying to join 4 tables, It is throwing me following exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.517] failure: identifier expected
>
> Query to join 4 tables:
>
> SELECT name, dueAmount FROM (SELECT name, age, gender, dpi.msisdn,
>   subscriptionType, maritalStatus, isHighARPU, ipAddress, startTime,
>   endTime, isRoaming, dpi.totalCount, dpi.website FROM (SELECT
>   subsc.name, subsc.age, subsc.gender, subsc.msisdn,
>   subsc.subscriptionType, subsc.maritalStatus, subsc.isHighARPU,
>   cdr.ipAddress, cdr.startTime, cdr.endTime, cdr.isRoaming FROM
>   SUBSCRIBER_META subsc, CDR_FACT cdr WHERE subsc.msisdn = cdr.msisdn
>   AND cdr.isRoaming = 'Y') temp, DPI_FACT dpi WHERE temp.msisdn =
>   dpi.msisdn) inner, BILLING_META billing where inner.msisdn =
>   billing.msisdn

can anyone please help me making this query work?

Thanks in advance. Error is as follow:

```
09/02/2015 02:55:24 [ERROR] org.apache.spark.Logging$class: Error running job streaming job 1423479307000 ms.0
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.517] failure: identifier expected

 SELECT name, dueAmount FROM (SELECT name, age, gender, dpi.msisdn, subscriptionType, maritalStatus, isHighARPU, ipAddress, startTime, endTime, isRoaming, dpi.totalCount, dpi.website FROM (SELECT subsc.name, subsc.age, subsc.gender, subsc.msisdn, subsc.subscriptionType, subsc.maritalStatus, subsc.isHighARPU, cdr.ipAddress, cdr.startTime, cdr.endTime, cdr.isRoaming FROM SUBSCRIBER_META subsc, CDR_FACT cdr WHERE subsc.msisdn = cdr.msisdn AND cdr.isRoaming = 'Y') temp, DPI_FACT dpi WHERE temp.msisdn = dpi.msisdn) inner, BILLING_META billing where inner.msisdn = billing.msisdn
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser.apply(SqlParser.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext.sql(JavaSQLContext.scala:49)
        at com.hp.tbda.rta.examples.JdbcRDDStreaming5$7.call(JdbcRDDStreaming5.java:596)
        at com.hp.tbda.rta.examples.JdbcRDDStreaming5$7.call(JdbcRDDStreaming5.java:546)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:527)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:527)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you try changing the name of alias from inner to something else

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurred due to you have used the reserved keyword "inner" of Spark in your sql. Avoid using of [Keywords in Spark SQL](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlSupportedSyntax.html) as custom identifier.